# Load Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, imagem, twitter-bootstrap

Estou desenvolvendo um portal, com Bootstrap (3.1).

Para isso coloquei um carousel igual do bootstrap no `HEADER` da página e o conteúdo logo abaixo desse carousel. É aqui que ocorre o problema, ao carregar a página, como as imagens tem um certo peso - 200kb aprox., o conteúdo que fica abaixo da página "sobe" até que a imagem seja carregada.

A minha dúvida é: como fazer o carousel do bootstrap ter um load para aguardar a imagem ser carregada, sem a página ficar "dançando"?

Obs.: A imagem varia na altura, logo, não consigo colocar um `height` ou `min-height` no div do carousel, para delimitar o tamanho inicial dele.

---

Quanto ao código é exatamente como o do Bootstrap com um "h2" e um "p" abaixo. Conforme abaixo:

```html
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>

  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
  </a>
</div> 
<h2>Título da Página</h2>
<p>Texto texto texto</p>
```

Comment: 200k!?!? Não dá pra otimizar isso não (jpg 60-80%)?

Comment: Você poderia colar alguns trechos do código, pode ajudar na hora de responder.

Comment: 200k em 60%, são imagens de 2000x600px, por isso o tamanho "absurdo".

Comment: @OniltonMaciel, segue código na pergunta.

Comment: Sem usar `min-height`? É como perguntar: "Estou com sede... o que faço? Mas não posso tomar líquidos nem receber soro porque sou alérgico a líquidos e injeções." - tipo missão impossível. Acho que você pode e deve usar `min-height`. Aproveite e também [use a classe `img-responsive` na sua tag `img`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-responsive-images).

Comment: Você pode, no server-side, usando uma biblioteca que lida com imagens, [obter a altura exata da primeira imagem a ser carregada](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2179126/370290). Então aplique essa altura no `min-height`.

Comment: @J.Bruni Pois é, justamente por isso que se torna complicado, por a imagem sempre ser responsiva! Se pudesse o min-height já estava no html. Vou verificar o que foi repassado de obter a altura da imagem e repasso o feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Caso você tenha uma média no tempo de carregamento do carrossel, você pode esconde-lo e exibir ele somente após carregado, +- assim:

```css
.carousel-inner {
      display: none;
}
```

ai você insere um script:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
     $('.carousel-inner').show("slow");
}
,3000);//aqui você ajusta os milisegundos pra exibir o carrossel
```

Dessa forma, alem de esperar carregar pra exibir, ele não aparece de uma vez, aparece de uma forma mais agradável ao usuário, e ainda existem outras opções para passar no `.show` pra que o carrossel seja carregado da forma que você achar melhor...

Comment: Acabei por utilizando essa forma. Se não pode com o erro, junte-se a ele e faça ficar "elegante". Obrigado @KennyRafael

Comment: Pois é...as vezes alguns "métodos alternativos" são necessários. xD

Answer (score 0):

Se salvar as imagens novamente for uma opção, eu tentaria salvar como JPEG progressivo, o browser começará a exibir a imagem pouco a pouco já no tamanho certo antes dela estar 100% baixada

Comment: Infelizmente mesmo com o JPEG progressivo a imagem continua não funcionando como deveria. Ele não carrega o espaço em um primeiro momento, mas sim vai carregando as imagens em "fatias" o que não gostaria que ocorresse.